# Sampling alternating blocks of character strings (words) from two fixed lists in R

Tags: r, string, sampling

I am attempting to create a 5000 word vector composed of 500 blocks of 10 words. One block is drawn from sampling with replacement from a fixed list of animals, and this block is to alternate with a fixed list of foods. The following code yields one iteration of what I need:

```
anim<- data.frame(cbind(stim=list.sample(animals$WORD, 10, replace=T), cond="animal"))
food <- data.frame(cbind(stim=list.sample(foods$WORD, 10, replace=T), cond="food"))
both <- data.frame(rbind(anim, food))
```

This yields output as follows:
[image: one iteration of sampling]

I just cannot figure out how to repeat this procedure 499 more times to create the total vector I need -- I will be running semantic distances between clusters to determine whether I can autosegment the boundaries between foods and animals. I attempted a repeat loop to no avail

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not provide any reproducible data, we will assume that `LETTERS` are food and `letters` are animals. This line of code generates the vector you specified. Here we are only using batches of 5 to illustrate the process:

```
result <- as.vector(replicate(5, c(sample(LETTERS, 5, replace=TRUE), sample(letters, 5, replace=TRUE))))
result
#  [1] "H" "O" "T" "K" "J" "m" "c" "s" "u" "c" "P" "Y" "V" "U" "Y" "p" "u" "q" "k" "l" "B" "H" "U" "F" "K" "h" "v" "g"
# [29] "c" "d" "X" "F" "R" "N" "U" "v" "t" "u" "q" "x" "N" "E" "G" "Q" "L" "d" "a" "v" "e" "a"
```